# Django/Pillow - Image resize only if image is uploaded

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, python-imaging-library

I'm able to upload an image and resize it, but if I submit the form without images I get this error

`The 'report_image' attribute has no file associated with it.`

What should I do if no image is uploaded?

This is my `models.py`

```py
class Report(models.Model):

    options = (
        ('active', 'Active'),
        ('archived', 'Archived'),
    )

    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    description = models.TextField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    reporter_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    reporter_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    reporter_email = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    reporter_phone = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    report_image = models.ImageField(_("Image"), upload_to=upload_to, null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=options, default='active')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-date',)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        img = Image.open(self.report_image.path)

        if img.height > 1080 or img.width > 1920:
            new_height = 720
            new_width = int(new_height / img.height * img.width)
            img = img.resize((new_width, new_height))
            img.save(self.report_image.path)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. Needed to add this check before the actual resize.

`if self.report_image:`

This way, if no image has been uploaded it will just ignore the resize and proceed without it.

This is the new relevant part:

```py
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        if self.report_image: #check if image exists before resize
            img = Image.open(self.report_image.path)

            if img.height > 1080 or img.width > 1920:
                new_height = 720
                new_width = int(new_height / img.height * img.width)
                img = img.resize((new_width, new_height))
                img.save(self.report_image.path)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?